# Attempt to present QLPreviewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to open UIDocumentInteraction Controller but view is not in the hierarchy. can any one please help me to resolve it.

Comment: Can you post how and where (which method) you are trying to present it?

Comment: i am downloading a file from web and doing this

Comment: Try doing it from the main thread. Again post your  code.

Comment: how can i do it from main thread

Comment: Using DispatchQueue

Comment: func showFileWithPath(path: String){
        
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let isFileFound:Bool? = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path)
                if isFileFound == true{
                    let viewer = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
                    viewer.delegate = self
                viewer.presentPreview(animated: true)
            }
            
        }
        
    }

Comment: but not working

Comment: [Edit] your question with all relevant details and code. Do not post code in comments.

Comment: can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in the fact that you're not keeping a reference to your `UIDocumentInteractionController` instance as a property of your view controller. Try something like this:

```
var documentInteractionController: UIDocumentInteractionController?

...

func showFileWithPath(path: String) {
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
        documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        documentInteractionController?.delegate = self
        documentInteractionController?.presentPreview(animated: true)
    }
}
```